# Conversation Learner: demo-pizza - ERROR: Missing ConversationReference

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, conversationlearner

I run the Demo Pizza bot (npm run demo-pizza) and then click the Log Dialog section and try to order a pizza. It works, but I see this in the command window with each reply:

> ERROR: Missing ConversationReference

Comment: Hi Michael - do you still see this issue with the latest version?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test yet. Hope to do so in the next three weeks.

Comment: Cool.  Let me know if you continue to see issues.  Thx

Comment: are you positive you used in your command line "npm run demo-pizza"?

Comment: @Ferdinand Fejskid - No I am not sure. Unfortunately it was 4 months ago.